# Why bermuda.c filters all the data?

Tags: c, windows

**bermuda.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
 float latitude;
 float longitude;
 char info[80];
 while (scanf("%f, %f, %79[79^n]",&latitude ,&longitude ,info ) == 3)
   if ((latitude > 26) && (latitude < 34))
     if ((longitude > -76) && (longitude < -64))
       printf("%f, %f, %s\n", latitude, longitude, info);

return 0;
}
```

**geo2json.c**:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()

{
  float latitude;
  float longitude;
  char info[80];
  int started = 0;

  puts("data=[");
  while (scanf("%f,%f,%79[^\n]", &latitude, &longitude, info) == 3) {
    if (started)
       printf(",\n");
    else
       started = 1;
    if ((latitude < -90.0) || (latitude > 90.0)){
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid latitude : %f\n", latitude);
        return 2;
    }   if ((longitude < -180.0) || (longitude > 180.0)){
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid longitude : %f\n", longitude);
        return 2;
    }
    printf("{latitude: %f, longitude : %f, info: '%s'}",latitude, longitude, info);
    }
    puts("\n]");
    return 0;
}
```

But when I enter

```
(bermuda | geo2json) < spooky.csv
```

It happens likscreen:

```
data=[]
```

There are no data shown on the screen

`Bermuda.c` are supposed to filter the `((latitude > 26) && (latitude < 34))` and `((longitude > -76) && (longitude < -64))` ,but it filter all the data in `spooky.csv` and there is some data in it meet the criteria of `((latitude > 26) && (latitude < 34))` and `((longitude > -76) && (longitude < -64))`

Comment: Your problem seems unclear.  Could you clarify a bit? Also, show the contents of `spooky.csv` and show the expected output and the actual output. And is `%79[79^n]` a typo?

Comment: What does `bermuda < spooky.csv` print?

Comment: What happens if you throw out the filter conditions and print every location? It could be that the wrong `scanf` format that Cool Guy pointed out garbles the input. Use the `scanf` format from **geo2json.c** in **bermuda.c**, too. That format looks good, it reads two floats and then everything up to the new line.

Comment: 30.685163 -68.137207 Type=Yeti
30.685163 -74.575195 Type=UFO
30.685163 -71.136475 Type=Ship
30.685163 -62.753906 Type=Elvis
30.685163 -68.005371 Type=Goatsucker
30.685163 -73.33374 Type=Disappearance
30.685163 -71.477051 Type=UFO
30.685163 -66.027832 Type=Ship
30.685163 -69.477539 Type=Elvis
30.685163 -68.192139 Type=Elvis
30.685163 -87.484131 Type=Elvis

Comment: This is the data in spooky.csv

Comment: Thank you guys , the     %79[79^n] should be     %79[^\n]